# Typescript: iterate through checkbox (made by ngfor) and print value of each checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I want to get value `(console.log(somevalue))`  from each of my checkbox generated by `ngfor` . My form is displaying OK.

Here is code :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let firstColumn of mapMenusFirstColumn; index as i;">
    <label class="col-4">{{firstColumn}}</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline"
        *ngFor="let secondColumn of this.getSecondColumn(this.mapMenu,firstColumn); index as j;">
        
        <input name="checkbox{{i}}" id="checkbox{{i+'_'+j}}" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
          value={{secondColumn}}>
        <label for="checkbox{{i+'_'+j}}" class="custom-control-label">{{secondColumn}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is design :

[image]

I need to iterate though all of my checkbox and `console.log()` each check box value. Please help me

(Note that : see how I generated Id and Name - it is like :

when name 1 id is 1_1 , 1_2 ..

when name 2 id is 2_1, 2_2, 2_3, ...

Should I change my id , name implementation for this purpose ? If so please tell me about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use Reactive Forms. First create a FormGroup in the component based on the first and second columns in your arrays like so:

```
 buildReactiveForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.mapMenusFirstColumn.forEach((firstColumnItem, firstIndex) => {
      this.getSecondColumn(this.mapMenu, firstColumnItem).forEach(
        (secondColumnItem, secondIndex) => {
          this.form.addControl(
            "checkbox" + firstIndex + "_" + secondIndex,
            new FormControl(false)
          );
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

And in your HTML file add another attribute for the  tag specifying the form control name

```
<input name="checkbox{{i}}" id="checkbox{{i+'_'+j}}" formControlName="checkbox{{i+'_'+j}}" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
```

And, finally, you can log the values of the checkboxes by simply logging the form's value

```
console.log(this.form.value)
```

Which will have the following output
[image]

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/questions63098875?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: you stackblitz is very impressive. it is very close to my code. you are generating all boxes blank "before displaying page". I also want that .

I also want an extra thing, that is . lets stay 10 of 2 checkboxes will be cheked "before displaying page" from typescript. [ I will have determine it by check checkbox value with an array.I repeat I must do it "before loading page" from typescript.

If you have time, please consider to update your stackblitz. Thanks in advance.

And also a lot of thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by before displaying the page. If you need to set the value for some checkboxes simply create a method and call this.form.get("checkbox" + 1 + "_" + 1).setValue(true); for whichever checkbox you want to check. Call that method after initializing the form. Updated stackblitz